# How to remove 'null' from an array?

Tags: reactjs

I receive a response from the backend that gives me an array of language, which one is default, but the two other languages comes with different varibales.(Also need to split them in order to take the language string)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('api')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setLanguage([...language, response.data.data.LANGUAGE1_NAME.split("-")[1], response?.data?.data?.LANGUAGE2_NAME == undefined ? 'null' : response.data.data.LANGUAGE2_NAME.split("-")[1], response?.data?.data?.LANGUAGE3_NAME == undefined ? 'null' : response.data.data.LANGUAGE3_NAME.split("-")[1]])
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

So when I pass the the language to the child component, in one scenario I might pass it like this
language["English", "null", "null"].
So in the child component, I display them in an input, and what I'm trying to do is to remove the `"null"` from the list.
I tried this

```
<div>
  <input
     type="text"
     value={language == 'null' ? language.pop() : language}
     onChange={(event) => handleItemChanged(event, i)}
     placeholder="Language"
  />
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I remove the "null" from the array ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

```
let array = [0, 1, null, 2, 3];

function removeNull(array) {
    return array.filter(x => x !== null)
};
```

Other way:

```
const filteredArray = [1, null, undefined, 2].filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
let a = [1,2,4,6,null,'A',undefined,'B'].filter(x => !x===false);
```

Here, it will remove `undefined` as well.

Or even:

```
let a = [1,2,4,6,null,'A',undefined,'B'].filter(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there `null` is a `string`, you can filter your array and remove the values:

```
language = language.filter(element => element !== 'null')
```